# DataContext clear delete changeset

Tags: c#, linq, datacontext

I have a table in my database that is getting cleaned up periodically. I am getting a list of the items that need to be removed and then iterating through them to delete them from the database. The issue is that some of the deletes will violate a foreign key constraint. This is fine and I just want to ignore these items and move on. The problem is as soon as one fails it gets stuck in the delete queue for the data context and I cant continue on. From my research it seems that you cant just clear the delete queue in .NET 4. How can I just move on after a delete fails?

```
using (DataContext dc = new DataContext())
{
    List<Item> removedItems = dc.Items.Where(o => o.Removed).ToList();

    foreach (Item item in removedItems)
    {
        try
        {
            dc.Items.DeleteOnSubmit(item);
            dc.SubmitChanges();
        }
        catch { }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if it work or not but, but just try adding "continue;" statement in your catch block, so it process next item when violation exception occures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this combination that works. I have been messing with versions of this all day and this finally gave me what I needed. I guess just inserting the item back negates the delete.

```
using (DataContext dc = new DataContext())
{
    List<Item> removedItems = dc.Items.Where(o => o.Removed).ToList();

    foreach (Item item in removedItems)
    {
        try
        {
            dc.Items.DeleteOnSubmit(item);
            dc.SubmitChanges();
        }
        catch 
        { 
            dc.StatisticsSettings.InsertOnSubmit(item);
        }
    }
}
```